# Outlook deforms my mail

Tags: email, outlook, mailchimp, newsletter

I'm doing a newsletter with mailchimp.
But when I send a test mail to myself, Outlook deforms it, is it normal?

I tried to change it to HTML but it doesn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is normal, doing e-mails is tricky.

Please share with use the markup.

Build e-mails have a lot of tweaks and tricks. You might have some compatibility issue on your code.